# Work offline in Google Drive on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, google-docs

Is there a way to work offline on a Google Drive document on an iPad?

I'm aware it's possible on a desktop or laptop when using Chrome, but I can't seem to see an option for such a functionality in the Google Drive app.

You can make a file available offline, but you can only view it if you do that.  I can't seem to be able to edit it though.

I was reading an [article on the Google Docs blog](http://googledocs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/announcing-your-two-most-requested.html), but it doesn't seem clear to me whether offline editing is one thing and the app is another, or if offline editing is a feature of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link in the article you mentioned where it says the following:

> "The Google Drive app for iPhone and iPad lets you view items you've stored in Google Drive with your device even when it isn't connected to the Internet or a mobile network. **Offline editing isn’t currently supported.**"

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=107975

Comment: @sam, I'm assuming they will add this in a future update. It is correct that at least as of version 1.1.2699 offline editing doesn't work. Hopefully you can tether or something.

Comment: cheers, cant see how i missed that

Comment: The really frustrating thing is that an earlier version of the app did support offline editing. Google just disabled it in an update.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs for iPad now supports off line editing: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-docs/id842842640?mt=8

Under the listed features:

> Get stuff done anytime -- even without an internet connection

I have just tested it out on my iPad mini, and it worked fine off line, syncing and updating the shared document once I connected again.