# Files app on ipad to access local files and file synced on Google Drive or OneDrive

Tags: ipad

I'm trying to find out how to get my ipad to have files available locally (if/when I'm not connected to the internet) but that are also synced with my desktop.
IPad OS Version is: 15.4.1

I'm sure the standard answer is to use Apple iCloud, but if possible because I'm running windows I'd prefer Google Drive, O365 OneDrive or Dropbox.

- Dropbox: First tried dropbox (see https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/mobile/access-files-offline).  It required an upgrade.  I no longer have premium paid for version of Dropbox, but do have Google Drive, and O365 OneDrive for Business.
- Tried OneDrive for Business.  Opened the app and was able get files to appear on iPad but can't get them to be available offline and wasn't able to get Apple's File App to see OneDrive.

Comment: You should be able to add OneDrive as a location in Files. Doesn‘t it show up there? Same for Google Drive.

Comment: Why does it need to be Apple's Files app why not just the OneDrive or Google apps?

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/216600/237

Comment: @nohillside, I've read that I should be able to add OneDrive as a location in **Files** app but for some reason I don't have that as an option, and I'm not sure how to enable it.

Comment: @mmmmmm, I'm fine with it beeing **OneDrive** or **Google Drive** but my files are currently on my local iPad so they only show up in **Files** app... So somehow, I need to get them transferred to the other choices.

Comment: @mmmmmm, I'll have to try **Google Docs** (per your link).